# Why should we not store onions and potatoes together?

Tags: storage

I have heard that onions and potatoes shouldn't be stored together. Why will this make the potatoes spoil faster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see at the *Chapter 7: Storage of horticultural crops* of the book [PDF: **Small-Scale Postharvest Handling Practices: A Manual for Horticultural Crops (4th Edition)**](http://www.share4dev.info/kb/documents/5105.pdf):

- If you look *p.166* (*p.173* on the PDF), you can see that the **onions** need to be stored in this conditions:

  - **between *0-5°C*** with a **relative humidity (*R.H.*) of *65-70%***
- If you look *p.168* (*p.175* on the PDF), you can see that the **potatoes** have different needs:

  - **Fresh market**: between *4-7°C*
  - **Processing**: between *8-12°C*
  - **seed potatoes**: between *0-2°C*
  - **But must of all, potatoes need very highest relative humidity (*R.H.*): *95-98%* versus *65-70%* for onions**

So, if you store them together, either one or the other will be in bad storage conditions.

Further, as you can see at [*Section 7: Storage of horticultural crops* of **Small-scale postharvest handling practices - A manual for horticultural crops - 3rd edition**](http://www.fao.org/WAIRdocs/x5403e/x5403e09.htm#section%207%3a%20storage%20of%20horticultural%20crops):

- **Dry onions** (*Group 3*) are very sensitive to moisture, which makes their storage incompatible with the high *R.H.* needed for **potatoes**.
- **New potatoes** (*Group 6*) may also produce ethylene, which will badly damage **green onions** (*Group 2*) if stored together.

Anyway, storage of horticultural crops cannot just be resumed by "*don't put this or that together*", as you may have seen:
it is important to consider *R.H.*, temperature, and many other factors.

If the subject interests you, all this (and many other things) is pretty well explained in the following references:

- [PDF: **Small-Scale Postharvest Handling Practices: A Manual for Horticultural Crops (4th Edition)**](http://www.share4dev.info/kb/documents/5105.pdf)
- [Web: **Small-Scale Postharvest Handling Practices: A Manual for Horticultural Crops (4th Edition)**](http://www.fao.org/docrep/009/ae075e/ae075e00.htm)
- [WEB: **Small-scale postharvest handling practices - A manual for horticultural crops - 3rd edition**](http://www.fao.org/WAIRdocs/x5403e/x5403e00.htm)

Ethylene is also a "*critical factor*", and this topic is more developped in the following resources:

- [PDF: **Postharvest Ethylene: A critical factor in quality management.**](http://www.postharvest.com.au/EthylenePDF.PDF)
- [Book: **Postharvest Technology of Horticultural Crops** (see *Ethylene in Postharvest Technology pp.149-162*)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1879906511)

Comment: This answer makes me think that, if RH and temperature are fixed, there should be no significant effect on potato spoilage (due to the presence/absence of onions).  That contradicts the other answer, but maybe this older thinking is a myth; is there any published experiment to check this?  It sounds like a good time lapse science experiment candidate.

Answer (score 2):

When stored together, onions release gases that will cause the potatoes to spoil faster and become mushy, if you will.

Comment: This is the simple and correct answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your potatoes with your onions, your potatoes will begin to grow eyes (stems). I like to put these two together only to start my potatoes off before I plant them. It is a much faster process, instead of starting from seeds. Hope this helps!